# Why are certain class instantiations apparently not being converted properly to json?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, html, razor

I am generating the contents of a div's content on a page by calling getJSON on a razor/cshtml file. 90% of the code works - from 2013 down through 1960 - as you can see at http://www.awardwinnersonly.com/ by selecting "Hugos (Science Fiction)" from the book dropdown, but something in the last few "records" I added (from 1959 to 1946) is apparently causing the call to getJSON('getHugos.cshtml') to fail, as with those additional records the page does not display at all.

(The problem "records" are commented out for now)

Note: The "records" with funky vals such as "blankThis" and "blankThat" and where category is set to a year are not a problem; they are just rather kludgy - if category is four chars in length, the "record" is a year, and it is processed differently.

Also, the elements with "--" as their value are not a problem - in those cases, no corresponding button is created (for the Kindle, Hardcopy, or Paperback edition).

Here is a subset of the code in the cshtml file. The ellipsis dots represent lots of elided "records"; the bulk of it, apparently where the problem lies, is after the second set of ellipsis dots and the comment:

```
@{
    var books = new List<BookClass>
    {
        new BookClass{Year=2013, YearDisplay="blankYearDisplay", Category="2013", Title="blankTitle", Author="blankAuthor", KindleASIN="blankKindleASIN", HardboundASIN="blankHardboundASIN",   
PaperbackASIN="blankPaperbackASIN", ImgSrc="blankImgSrc"},
. . .
new BookClass{Year=2001, YearDisplay="2001", Category="Best Novella", Title="The Ultimate Earth", Author="Jack Williamson", KindleASIN="B00DV8TSHO", HardboundASIN="--", PaperbackASIN="1612421547",   
ImgSrc="http:images.amazon.com/images/P/B00DV8TSHO.01.MZZZZZZZ"}
. . . 
// the above works, from 2013 down to 1960, but something in the last few "records" is apparently causing it to fail
        new BookClass{Year=1959, YearDisplay="blankYearDisplay", Category="1959", Title="blankTitle", Author="blankAuthor", KindleASIN="blankKindleASIN", HardboundASIN="blankHardboundASIN", PaperbackASIN="blankPaperbackASIN", ImgSrc="blankImgSrc"},
        new BookClass{Year=1959, YearDisplay="1959", Category="Best Novel", Title="A Case of Conscience", Author="James Blish", KindleASIN="--", HardboundASIN="B000J52BAI", PaperbackASIN="0345438353",     
ImgSrc="http:images.amazon.com/images/P/0345438353.01.MZZZZZZZ"},
        new BookClass{Year=1958, YearDisplay="blankYearDisplay", Category="1958", Title="blankTitle", Author="blankAuthor", KindleASIN="blankKindleASIN", HardboundASIN="blankHardboundASIN",     
PaperbackASIN="blankPaperbackASIN", ImgSrc="blankImgSrc"},
        new BookClass{Year=1958, YearDisplay="1958", Category="Best Novel", Title="The Big Time", Author="Fritz Leiber", KindleASIN="B004UJHII4", HardboundASIN="0899685374", PaperbackASIN="B003YMNGGG",     
ImgSrc="http:images.amazon.com/images/P/B004UJHII4.01.MZZZZZZZ"},
        new BookClass{Year=1956, YearDisplay="blankYearDisplay", Category="1956", Title="blankTitle", Author="blankAuthor", KindleASIN="blankKindleASIN", HardboundASIN="blankHardboundASIN",     
PaperbackASIN="blankPaperbackASIN", ImgSrc="blankImgSrc"},
        new BookClass{Year=1956, YearDisplay="1956", Category="Best Novel", Title="Double Star", Author="Robert A. Heinlein", KindleASIN="B0050OVMWG", HardboundASIN="0839824467", PaperbackASIN="0345330137",     
ImgSrc="http:images.amazon.com/images/P/B0050OVMWG.01.MZZZZZZZ"},
        new BookClass{Year=1955, YearDisplay="blankYearDisplay", Category="1955", Title="blankTitle", Author="blankAuthor", KindleASIN="blankKindleASIN", HardboundASIN="blankHardboundASIN",     
PaperbackASIN="blankPaperbackASIN", ImgSrc="blankImgSrc"},
        new BookClass{Year=1955, YearDisplay="1955", Category="Best Novel", Title="They'd Rather Be Right (also known as The Forever Machine)", Author="Mark Clifton and Frank Riley", KindleASIN="--", HardboundASIN="--",     
PaperbackASIN="0881848425", ImgSrc="http:images.amazon.com/images/P/0881848425.01.MZZZZZZZ"},
        new BookClass{Year=1954, YearDisplay="blankYearDisplay", Category="1954", Title="blankTitle", Author="blankAuthor", KindleASIN="blankKindleASIN", HardboundASIN="blankHardboundASIN",     
PaperbackASIN="blankPaperbackASIN", ImgSrc="blankImgSrc"},
        new BookClass{Year=1954, YearDisplay="1954", Category="Best Novella", Title="A Case of Conscience", Author="James Blish", KindleASIN="--", HardboundASIN="B000M0BM5A", PaperbackASIN="B005KEM8TW",     
ImgSrc="http:images.amazon.com/images/P/B005KEM8TW.01.MZZZZZZZ"},
        new BookClass{Year=1953, YearDisplay="blankYearDisplay", Category="1953", Title="blankTitle", Author="blankAuthor", KindleASIN="blankKindleASIN", HardboundASIN="blankHardboundASIN",     
PaperbackASIN="blankPaperbackASIN", ImgSrc="blankImgSrc"},
        new BookClass{Year=1953, YearDisplay="1953", Category="Best Novel", Title="The Demolished Man", Author="Alfred Bester", KindleASIN="B00D2ITJLS", HardboundASIN="B000UF0KTQ", PaperbackASIN="0679767819",     
ImgSrc="http:images.amazon.com/images/P/B00D2ITJLS.01.MZZZZZZZ"},
        new BookClass{Year=1951, YearDisplay="blankYearDisplay", Category="1951", Title="blankTitle", Author="blankAuthor", KindleASIN="blankKindleASIN", HardboundASIN="blankHardboundASIN",     
PaperbackASIN="blankPaperbackASIN", ImgSrc="blankImgSrc"},
        new BookClass{Year=1951, YearDisplay="1951", Category="Best Novella", Title="The Man Who Sold the Moon", Author="Robert A. Heinlein", KindleASIN="B00ELJZZ24", HardboundASIN="--", PaperbackASIN="1451639228",     
ImgSrc="http:images.amazon.com/images/P/B00ELJZZ24.01.MZZZZZZZ"},
        new BookClass{Year=1946, YearDisplay="blankYearDisplay", Category="1946", Title="blankTitle", Author="blankAuthor", KindleASIN="blankKindleASIN", HardboundASIN="blankHardboundASIN",     
PaperbackASIN="blankPaperbackASIN", ImgSrc="blankImgSrc"},
        new BookClass{Year=1946, YearDisplay="1946", Category="Best Novella", Title="Animal Farm", Author="George Orwell", KindleASIN="B003ZX868W", HardboundASIN="0151010269", PaperbackASIN="184046254X",     
ImgSrc="http:images.amazon.com/images/P/B003ZX868W.01.MZZZZZZZ"}
    };
    Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    Json.Write(books, Response.Output);
}
```

Surely strings such as "They'd Rather Be Right (also known as The Forever Machine)" are not a problem, are they? Obviously, it compiles and runs...

When possible, I will try stepping through getHugos.cshtml; also, looking in the browser console to see if there are any err msgs, but does anybody know anything about the vagaries of getJSON related to cshtml files that could shed some light on this conundrum?

### UPDATE

Rearranging and reformatting it this way:

```
var books = new List<BookClass> {
    new BookClass{Year=1959, YearDisplay="blankYearDisplay", Category="1959", Title="blankTitle", Author="blankAuthor", KindleASIN="blankKindleASIN", HardboundASIN="blankHardboundASIN", PaperbackASIN="blankPaperbackASIN", ImgSrc="blankImgSrc"},
    new BookClass{Year=1958, YearDisplay="blankYearDisplay", Category="1958", Title="blankTitle", Author="blankAuthor", KindleASIN="blankKindleASIN", HardboundASIN="blankHardboundASIN", PaperbackASIN="blankPaperbackASIN", ImgSrc="blankImgSrc"},
    new BookClass{Year=1956, YearDisplay="blankYearDisplay", Category="1956", Title="blankTitle", Author="blankAuthor", KindleASIN="blankKindleASIN", HardboundASIN="blankHardboundASIN", PaperbackASIN="blankPaperbackASIN", ImgSrc="blankImgSrc"},
    new BookClass{Year=1955, YearDisplay="blankYearDisplay", Category="1955", Title="blankTitle", Author="blankAuthor", KindleASIN="blankKindleASIN", HardboundASIN="blankHardboundASIN", PaperbackASIN="blankPaperbackASIN", ImgSrc="blankImgSrc"},
    new BookClass{Year=1954, YearDisplay="blankYearDisplay", Category="1954", Title="blankTitle", Author="blankAuthor", KindleASIN="blankKindleASIN", HardboundASIN="blankHardboundASIN", PaperbackASIN="blankPaperbackASIN", ImgSrc="blankImgSrc"},
    new BookClass{Year=1953, YearDisplay="blankYearDisplay", Category="1953", Title="blankTitle", Author="blankAuthor", KindleASIN="blankKindleASIN", HardboundASIN="blankHardboundASIN", PaperbackASIN="blankPaperbackASIN", ImgSrc="blankImgSrc"},
    new BookClass{Year=1951, YearDisplay="blankYearDisplay", Category="1951", Title="blankTitle", Author="blankAuthor", KindleASIN="blankKindleASIN", HardboundASIN="blankHardboundASIN", PaperbackASIN="blankPaperbackASIN", ImgSrc="blankImgSrc"},
    new BookClass{Year=1946, YearDisplay="blankYearDisplay", Category="1946", Title="blankTitle", Author="blankAuthor", KindleASIN="blankKindleASIN", HardboundASIN="blankHardboundASIN", PaperbackASIN="blankPaperbackASIN", ImgSrc="blankImgSrc"},

    new BookClass{Year=1959, YearDisplay="1959", Category="Best Novel",   Title="A Case of Conscience",                                       Author="James Blish",                  KindleASIN="--",         HardboundASIN="B000J52BAI", PaperbackASIN="0345438353", ImgSrc="http:images.amazon.com/images/P/0345438353.01.MZZZZZZZ"},
    new BookClass{Year=1958, YearDisplay="1958", Category="Best Novel",   Title="The Big Time",                                               Author="Fritz Leiber",                 KindleASIN="B004UJHII4", HardboundASIN="0899685374", PaperbackASIN="B003YMNGGG", ImgSrc="http:images.amazon.com/images/P/B004UJHII4.01.MZZZZZZZ"},
    new BookClass{Year=1956, YearDisplay="1956", Category="Best Novel",   Title="Double Star",                                                Author="Robert A. Heinlein",           KindleASIN="B0050OVMWG", HardboundASIN="0839824467", PaperbackASIN="0345330137", ImgSrc="http:images.amazon.com/images/P/B0050OVMWG.01.MZZZZZZZ"},
    new BookClass{Year=1955, YearDisplay="1955", Category="Best Novel",   Title="They'd Rather Be Right (also known as The Forever Machine)", Author="Mark Clifton and Frank Riley", KindleASIN="--",         HardboundASIN="--",         PaperbackASIN="0881848425", ImgSrc="http:images.amazon.com/images/P/0881848425.01.MZZZZZZZ"},
    new BookClass{Year=1954, YearDisplay="1954", Category="Best Novella", Title="A Case of Conscience",                                       Author="James Blish",                  KindleASIN="--",         HardboundASIN="B000M0BM5A", PaperbackASIN="B005KEM8TW", ImgSrc="http:images.amazon.com/images/P/B005KEM8TW.01.MZZZZZZZ"},
    new BookClass{Year=1953, YearDisplay="1953", Category="Best Novel",   Title="The Demolished Man",                                         Author="Alfred Bester",                KindleASIN="B00D2ITJLS", HardboundASIN="B000UF0KTQ", PaperbackASIN="0679767819", ImgSrc="http:images.amazon.com/images/P/B00D2ITJLS.01.MZZZZZZZ"},
    new BookClass{Year=1951, YearDisplay="1951", Category="Best Novella", Title="The Man Who Sold the Moon",                                  Author="Robert A. Heinlein",           KindleASIN="B00ELJZZ24", HardboundASIN="--",         PaperbackASIN="1451639228", ImgSrc="http:images.amazon.com/images/P/B00ELJZZ24.01.MZZZZZZZ"},
    new BookClass{Year=1946, YearDisplay="1946", Category="Best Novella", Title="Animal Farm",                                                Author="George Orwell",                KindleASIN="B003ZX868W", HardboundASIN="0151010269", PaperbackASIN="184046254X", ImgSrc="http:images.amazon.com/images/P/B003ZX868W.01.MZZZZZZZ"}
};
```

...indicates it's not a problem with the data, UNLESS the following is, indeed, problematic for some reason:

Title="They'd Rather Be Right (also known as The Forever Machine)"

### UPDATE 2

Somehow this ended up at the top of my getHugos.cshtml file - beats me how - :

```
/P/
```

...so that the first line was:

```
/P/@{
```

...and that's why it was failing.

It's bizarre and/or macrabre to me that it would even compile - in fact, it would be nice if it wouldn't, and point me to that line!

But thanks for your tip on the unmatched alt tag, JayC - it wasn't causing the html to fail, but I'm sure it was messing up my alts.

Comment: I think you're attacking the problem wrong; how exactly do you know you have the issue? How are you using the JSON to render content? Also, how exactly is it being included in the `.cshtml` file? Is the output part of a script tag or something?

Comment: I know I have the issue because the content is no longer being displayed. It works for all the others; in fact, it's working NOW on the live site, because the problem code (above) is commented out. I'm using JSON in both cases via jQuery calls to getJSON(). In the early cases, it was getJSON('Bla.json'). In this case, it is getJSON('getHugos.cshtml'); that Razor file, as shown above in the original post, then converts those classes to JSON and returns them.

Comment: "...the content is no longer being displayed."  I can interpret that  several ways.  Does a request with `.getJSON` appear to succeed, but no new content is rendered into the browser?  Does the request succeed, and new content is rendered, but when it appears to come across a problematic entry, does it stop? Does some failure appear to muck up all future requests, regardless of what was requested?  Related questions: Are you using a templating system or some custom thing to render html from the JSON for the browser?  What errors are you seeing in your browser's console?

Comment: My point is, you need to see if your problem really is a JSON issue or a rendering issue (or maybe both).  From what you've shown, I can't tell.  (A second point I probably ought to mention is that calling a razor template without a controller is a little weird, and certainly not the normal practice to generate JSON; I'm surprised it's even working at all.  A more common usage is to have a controller return a JSONResult or something along those lines; you wouldn't even need a razor view. )

Comment: MVC would be overkill for this site, IMO. After all, the logic is simply: the user selects the award they want to see, and the relevant content gets loaded. If they click on a button in that rendered content, it loads another external (amazon) page. Nothing too fancy. And I got the example of how to do this (C#/Razor > JSON) from a book by Mike Brind - pages 168-172 or so of his Web Matrix book. So, it would be surprising if it *didn't* work, I think. Truth be told, I'm usually a trifle surprised when something works for the first time, and not surprised but put out when something doesn't work

Comment: And BTW: Why would it not work? That code takes an object and converts it to json; why would it need to be part of some fancy-pants controller to work?

Comment: Now it makes sense, sorry. I completely forgot about WebMatrix.  I use that product all the time, but I've generally used it only to quickly set up for testing or edit pure html/javascript websites or more, uh, "conventional" asp.net websites; this usage of Razor outside of MVC is new to me but I remember hearing podcasts about it or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, It's pretty clear now.  I'm not sure where you got this htmlBuilder bits, but it's quite clear to me that this is a problem if not your problem. Let's take a look at your html generator for Hugos:

```
$.getJSON('GetHugos', function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, dataPoint) {
        if (IsClassYear(dataPoint.Category)) {
            htmlBuilder += '<div class=\"yearBanner\">' + dataPoint.Category + '</div>';
        } else {
            htmlBuilder += '<section class=\"wrapper\" ><a id=\"mainImage\" class=\"floatLeft\" href=\"' +
                Urlify(dataPoint.KindleASIN) + '\"' +
                ' target=\"_blank\"><img height=\"160\" width=\"107\" src=\"' +
                dataPoint.ImgSrc + '\ alt=\"' + dataPoint.Title + ' by ' + dataPoint.Author + ' book cover\ ></img></a>' +
                '<div id=\"prizeCategory\" class=\"categorySmallerFont\">' +
                dataPoint.Category +
                '</div><br/><cite id=\"prizeTitle\" >' +
                dataPoint.Title +
                '</cite><br/><div id=\"prizeArtist\" class=\"author\">' +
                dataPoint.Author +
                '</div><br/>';
            if (dataPoint.KindleASIN.trim().length > 2) {
                htmlBuilder += '<button><a href=\"' + Urlify(dataPoint.KindleASIN) + '\"' +
                    ' target=\"_blank\">Kindle</a></button>';
            }
            if (dataPoint.PaperbackASIN.trim().length > 2) {
                htmlBuilder += '<button><a href=\"' + Urlify(dataPoint.PaperbackASIN) + '\"' +
                    ' target=\"_blank\">Paperback</a></button>';
            }
            if (dataPoint.HardboundASIN.trim().length > 2) {
                htmlBuilder += '<button><a href=\"' + Urlify(dataPoint.HardboundASIN) + '\"' +
                    ' target=\"_blank\">Hardcover</a></button>';
            }
            htmlBuilder += '</section>';
        }//else
    }); //each
```

Even if we were to assume all the fields were properly html encoded (which generally, you wouldn't assume), that's doesn't produce valid html.

The lines

```
                ' target=\"_blank\"><img height=\"160\" width=\"107\" src=\"' +
                dataPoint.ImgSrc + '\ alt=\"' + dataPoint.Title + ' by ' + dataPoint.Author + ' book cover\ ></img></a>' +
```

appear to have missing quote ending marks for the image attributes `src` and `alt`.  Also, `img` can't have any child nodes, so just make it a single tag `<img />`, although strictly speaking, that's not causing you any problems.

```
                ' target=\"_blank\"><img height=\"160\" width=\"107\" src=\"' +
                dataPoint.ImgSrc + '\" alt=\"' + dataPoint.Title + ' by ' + dataPoint.Author + ' book cover\" /></a>' +
```

Generally, I avoid this by using some kind of client-side templating solution like you might find with underscore.js or something more fancy like the mustache, handlebars, knockout.js or Telerik's kendo grid.

Comment: I see what you mean about the missing "quote ending marks", but this code works (unless somehow part of it was copied wrong)...?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma after the closing } on "The Ultimate Earth".

Comment: I'll czech it out when I get home, but I think that just got stripped out I was copying and pasting code - after all, it worked through 1960. It wasn't until I added the final entries, from 1959 down to 1946, that the problem occurred.